# SQL Server Script - select xml child nodes of root as (n)varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

I need to create a SQL Server script and a part of the script is **selecting the names of the immediate child nodes of the root node and convert it to a `(n)varchar`**. I don't need the attributes or content of the node.

This is an example of the xml:

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = 
'
<config>
  <module1 />    
  <module2 />  
</config>
'
```

I want the result like this:

- module1
- module2

Note that the xml is **not hardcoded** and can have many different child nodes.

I've already taken a look at [this (msdn)link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) but at first sight it doesn't seem possible with those XML methods.

Many thanks,
Kjell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the XML of the child nodes you mentioned you can use the Query method, for example;

```
select 
    cast(@XML.query('//GuiConfiguration/Activities') as nvarchar(max)), 
    cast(@XML.query('//GuiConfiguration/Reservations') as nvarchar(max))
```

**EDIT: Answer to refined question**

To get the names of the immediate child nodes of the root you can use this;

```
select
    cast(t.c.query('local-name(.)') as nvarchar(max))
from
    @xml.nodes('//*[1]/child::node()') as t(c)
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I can't hardcode something. The only hardcoded part is the root 'GuiConfiguration'. Then I only need the name of the node and none of the attributes and child nodes.

Comment: In which case please improve your question and add some examples of what you do want.

Comment: So you want the name of the direct child nodes of the root?

Comment: Example is in my post.

From the xml example I only need the child nodes with no attributes ('activities' and 'reservations') as a (n)varchar.

Comment: Yes please :) now you understand my question

Comment: Thank you Rhys. Accepted as answer. Your code works perfect in my script.